# Height 100% causes unwanted scrollbars

Tags: html, css

I'm sure you have all seen a similar question before but nothing I've read fixes this.

Basically I have a div with height 100% which fills the view port. Inside this div I have a h1 tag with height of 40px and a un-ordered list of height 100% to fill the remaining height of the page.

Because of the 40px H1 tag, the page gets vertical scroll bars which I don't want.

Another answer on a similar question was to add `overflow:hidden` to the div. This worked for a while but I found and issue with this. When I get a **X** amount of list items that my unordered list requires scroll bars, I cannot see the very bottom couple of items because of the `overflow: hidden` on the div. Please see the link below for a demo:
([Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xcIsm)).

If anyone could help me out with this it would be much appreciated.

**HTML:**

```
<div>
  <h1>Header</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body,
h1,
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
}
div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
h1 {
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: 40px plus 100% is more than you can fit in a window. So either you have a scrollbar, or you don't have a scrollbar but then you can't see the hidden part of the div. What other choices would you want?

Comment: `ul { height: 90%; }` ?

Comment: @abhitalks That would work if the OP wouldn't expect the ul to be 100% high. And the window would have to be exactly 400px high.

Comment: you can use "min-height"

Answer (score 0):

Only one change is required - just set the body to height:auto or just omit it as that's the default

```
body {
  height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

make it from 'auto' to 'hidden'

Answer (score 0):

You can set height to AUTO or specify a min-height and a max-height.

**EXAMPLES:**

```
ul{
 /*
 It's one or the others
 */
    height:auto;
    min-height: 400px;
    max-height: 600px;
}
```

With min and max, the value in between (400 and 600) will be set by how much content there is.

And `overflow: auto;` might too be your problem, you can set this to `overflow: hidden;`

Answer (score 0):

This is what fixed it for me:

```
    body {
    height: auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}

div {
    height: 100%;
    width: 300px;
}

ul {
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Thus, adding height: auto and overflow:hidden to the body should get rid of the page's scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1: Using calc() function

If you are supporting modern browsers, you could use the `calc` function:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body, h1, ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
div.wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
}
h1 {
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    background: red;
    height: calc(100% - 40px);
    overflow: auto;
}
```

For the `ul` element, set the height to be `100% - 40px` and that will compute the exact height to fit `ul` in the remaining space.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/KNShL/

### Solution 2: Using absolute positioning

You can also use absolute positioning to fit `ul` precisely into the parent block.

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body, h1, ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
div.wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: 300px;
    position: relative;
}
h1 {
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    background: red;
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

In this case, set `position: relative` on the `div.wrapper` parent block and then use `position: absolute` on the child `ul` element, with the offsets set to `top: 40px`, `bottom: 0`, and `right: 0` and the width to 100%.

The absolute positioning approach should work in any of the older browsers that support CSS2.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/929sW/

Answer (score 0):

Always use the keyword "auto", figures in % will always make error or blur screen in html, i.e whenever screen will be changed it will not correct answer. ALso if you are using % then never give "padding" and "margin" acc to its parent. Always use screen for it.